Four fallen angels killing mankind
When the four fallen angels underneath the Euphrates River are released, are they to kill Believers in God, or just people who have not repented?

Rev 9:13-15 - Then the sixth angel sounded his trumpet, and I heard a
voice from the four horns of the golden altar before God saying to the
sixth angel with the trumpet, “Release the four angels who are bound
at the great river Euphrates.”  So the four angels who had been
prepared for this hour and day and month and year were released to
kill a third of mankind.


hi Faith, it doesn't say so we'll have to ask them!

Welcome faith. Revelation has many interpretations, including whether these are fallen angels or regular  angels who have been held back for the event. (BTW please include a bible verse when you ask questions here)

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Faith. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

A helpful clue further to what is stated in Revelation 9:13-15 is given in chapter 16, where the River Euphrates is mentioned again. But before looking at that, it is more than a little helpful to grasp that the whole book of Revelation has 7 sections. Your text is in section 3, while the one I mention is in section 5. But all the sections deal with the same matters, adding further information as to what has been portrayed in the previous sections. As explained in this book (from where I get my answer to this questions):

"Like seven parallel (but not equal) tracks traversing the side of a
mountain, each appearing at one extremity and passing from sight at
the other, one above another in parallel, yet varying in length
proportionately as the mountain increases in height to the topmost
peak, so appears the Book of Revelation.
It follows that each ascending traverse affords a different view,
yields a distinctive perspective, presents a new aspect, yet of the
same basic journey in principle from one extremity of departure to the
other. But as the elevation heightens, so the journey decreases, and
the heavenly vision unfolds with the more astonishing clarity, till at
last all lies revealed before and beneath the spiritual gaze of the
discerning reader.
The lowest traverse gives the greatest earthly detail, whereas the
highest, wellnigh in the clouds of heaven, present a glimpse of that
vast, panoramic sweep of time and space from the vantage of the
heavenly places. This suddenly makes everything clear and in an
instant sets all in perspective.
But from foothills to peak, in each ascending parallel traverse, there
is the same extremity of departure relative to the mountainside, and
the same relative destination at its opposite point." The Revelation
of Jesus Christ, John Metcalfe, pp.53-54
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

As the text in question is in section 3 and the one I point to is in section 5, this answer cannot be exhaustive.  Yet the twice mentioned 'river Euphrates' may help a little.
First, chapter 9 specifies that when those 4 angels are released, they "slay the third part of men". From the same book:

"The figure of a battle has been used repetitively towards the end of
various preceding parallel openings in the Book of the Revelation of
Jesus Christ, and therefore it is mo surprise to find the most
climactic imagery of all battled taken from the visionary figures of
the prophet Ezekiel and applied in the seventh and last parallel
division of the book. The allegorical concept of a great battle, with
two hundred thousand thousand fearsome horsemen, appeared under a
figure of dramatic vividness with the sounding of the sixth trumpet,
chapter 9:13-21, a prelude to the last trump. Metaphorical use of the
type of the land of Israel, and of the Euphrates, filled out this
passage." (Ibid p.567)

Note how chapter 9 details how this third part of men are killed: by the fire, and by the smoke, and by the brimstone which issued out of the mouths of the horses (verse 18). The 4 angels do not kill those men. Now comes proof of whether those men killed, and those who remain alive, are 'believers' or not.

"And the rest of the men which were not killed by these plagues yet
repented not of the works of their hands, that they should not worship
devils, and idols... Neither repented they of their murders, nor of
their sorceries, nor of their fornication, nor of their thefts."
Revelation 9:18-21 K.J.V.

Those who are killed, and those who remain, were, and are, evildoers in God's sight. All of them were, and are, unrepentant. All who were, and are, God's people, have repented and are saved by grace, whatever happens on Earth. God's angels assist them during the tribulations symbolically depicted in Revelation, while demons influence unrepentant ones to carry out all that list of evil in verse 20.

"But in chapter 16 this falls upon the present heavens and earth, and
upon men whilst still living in the world. Suddenly it shall fall.
'And the sixth angel poured out his vial upon the great river
Euphrates; and the water thereof was dried up, that the way of the
kings of the east might be prepared.' ...
"How aptly does the previous description of the sounding of the sixth
angel, with its dire consequences, chapter 9:13-21, fit the exposition
of chapter 16:12-14, and verse 16 [about the final battle of
Armageddon]...
"Whereas the sounding of the sixth trumpet resulted in the loosing of
the four angels bound in the great river Euphrates, at the last day
the pouring out of the vial of the sixth angel upon the great river
Euphrates causes the waters to dry up, Revelation 16:12. Clearly this
is the culmination of the vision previously unfolded, Revelation
9:14." (Ibid pp.442-3)

The book then goes on to deal with the symbolic significance of this river Euphrates - far too much to copy here. The subject is massive, which is why the book takes over 600 pages to detail those seven sections in Revelation, then link them together for the finale.
For the purpose of this question, the answer is that the 4 angels bound in the symbolic river Euphrates may or may not be "fallen", but they do not kill anyone. The symbolic horses they muster do the killing. Those 4 angels are under God's control, bound until a certain time when he commands their release for a particular purpose. And all who die are unrepentant sinners. They are not God's people. It is the beast out of the sea (given its power by the dragon) that makes war with the saints on Earth, to overcome them. See chapter 13 verses 1-8.

This will not completely answer the question because there is considerable debate about how to understand this prophecy under the sixth trumpet.  However, here are some facts that we can deduce from the text.

The released angels are not necessarily "fallen angels".  Indeed, they could be angels of God sent to destroy as occurred in various other times such as 2 Sam 24:16, 17, 1 Chron 21:12, 15, 16, Ps 78:49, 1 Cor 10:10, Heb 11:28, Ex 12:23, Rev 14:18, etc.

Indeed, we observe in Rev 9:15 says that these destroying angels "have been prepared for the hour and day and month and year" suggest that God had them ready/prepared for this exact point in time.  This hints that they might be four of God's angels and thus not fallen angels.

Under the fifth trumpet (Rev 9:1-11) the angels (these are definitely fallen angels) that harm can only harm those who do not have the seal of God (V4).  Eph 1:13, 4:30 say that the seal of God is accomplished by the Holy Spirit.  Thus, the angels in the fifth trumpet can distinguish between those sealed by the Holy Spirit and those who are not.  (Compare Rev 7:1-3.)  Whether something similar applies under the sixth trumpet, we are not told.

The voice that commands the four angels comes from within the temple of God, and from between the horns of the altar of incense; this presumable depicts the voice of God commanding these angels.

It is not clear whether the events described under the sixth trumpet are alluding to some historical battle or a yet future battle.  The former is unlikely as the size of the mounted troops is 200,000,000 - larger than any army that has ever existed!  Thus, this is likely to refer to either a yet future event or a spiritual battle not intended to be taken literally.


Expanding on the last point, a non-literal spiritual battle is more likely because the power of these horses (V19) is in their mouths and in their tails. Thus, it is not the riders that cause harm but their horses and the power of the tails appears to be alluding to Isa 9:15 where the tail refers to prophets who teach lies.

Firstly, everything that is announced by the trumpets in these two chapters (beginning ch8 v6) is implicitly God's answer to the prayers of the saints which are put forward in ch8 vv1-5. In other words, this is God's action against the persecuting world in response to the persecution. So the unbelieving and persecuting world are the intended victims of these plagues and woes.
Secondly, the purpose of the woes of ch9 is to punish the idolaters, murderers etc. and induce at least some of them to repent. This is what we learn from ch9 vv20-21, where we are told that, in spite of everything that has happened over the previous nineteen verses, "The rest of mankind, who were not killed by these plagues, did not repent of the works of their hands... nor did they repent of their murders or their sorceries or their immorality or their thefts."
